# Flutter passando dados entre telas

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou com uma duvida que acredito ser simples mas como nunca fiz desta forma estou com dificuldade. Quero passar os dados de um contato para outra tela do app.

Aonde aciono um ActionSheet que aparece a opção de editar o comentário do contato (que redireciona para a outra tela). Acredito que o erro seja passar os parâmetros necessários do contato através do botão, mas como ?

Tela do ActionSheet:

```
CupertinoButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                child: const Icon(
                  CupertinoIcons.pen,
                  semanticLabel: 'Editar',
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  showCupertinoModalPopup(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        //É necessário retornar aqui o actionsheet para pegar os
                        //dados do contato
                        return CupertinoActionSheet(
                          title: Text(model.contactsList[index]["fullname"]),
                          message:
                          Text(model.contactsList[index]["comentario"]),
                          cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Text("Sair"),
                          ),
                          //Itens do action sheet
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                              onPressed: () {
                            },
                              child: CupertinoButton(
                                child: Text("Editar comentario"),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              UpdateComent()));
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
```

Aqui esta a minha tela aonde pretendo fazer o update, porém, acusa o erro de estar recebendo null

```
The getter 'contactsList' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contactsList
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
Container file:///home/marcelo/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/vp%20App/aplicativo-vpeventos/lib/update.dart:48:19`
```

E quando clica neste "link" aponta para o `Container(child: CommentStyle();)`

No segundo bloco.

```
class UpdateComent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdateComentState createState() => _UpdateComentState();
}

class _UpdateComentState extends State<UpdateComent> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
          trailing: ScopedModel<UserModel>(
              model: UserModel(),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0)),
                  CupertinoButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      child: const Tooltip(
                        message: 'Back',
                        child: Text('Salvar comentario'),
                        excludeFromSemantics: true,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {

                      }),
                ],
              )),
        ),

        //Corpo da tela
        body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(builder: (context, child, model){
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child:
                  Container(
                    child: CommentStyle(
                    ),
                  ),

              );

        }));
  }
}

//Aqui monto o corpo da tela 
class CommentStyle extends StatelessWidget {
 const CommentStyle({this.index, this.model});


 final int index;
 final UserModel model;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //printei o index e ele retorna null
    print("print aqui");
    print(index);

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    StyleText("Nome:"),
                   Text(model.contactsList[index]["fullname"]),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    StyleText("Email:"),
                    Text(model.contactsList[index]["email"]),
                  ],
                ),
                StyleText("Edite o comentario do usuario no campo abaixo"),
                CupertinoTextField(
                  controller: _controllerComent,
                  maxLines: 7,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                          width: 1.0,
                          color: Colors.grey
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                  ),
                  placeholder: model.contactsList[index]["comentario"],
                ),
              ],
            )
          ),

        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro que ocorre? Em que momento aparece o erro? Nos informe o erro completo, dizer que "está recebendo NULL é muito genérico"

Comment: Editei a pergunta, acredito que desta forma fique mais claro

Comment: Sim, ficou mais detalhado, verifique minha resposta que te explico como resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que teu problema talvez esteja aqui:

```
    body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(builder: (context, child, model){
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child:
              Container(
                child: CommentStyle(
                ),
              ),

          );

    }));
```

Você está criando o `CommentStyle` sem passar os parâmetros...

**Modificações**

Na `ActionSheet` mude o botão para

```
CupertinoButton(
  child: Text("Editar comentario"),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                UpdateComent(index)));
  },
),
```

Modifique sua class `UpdateComent` para receber o parâmetro do INDEX

```
class UpdateComent extends StatefulWidget {
  UpdateComent({this.index});
  final Integer index;
  @override
  _UpdateComentState createState() => _UpdateComentState();
}

class _UpdateComentState extends State<UpdateComent> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
        trailing: ScopedModel<UserModel>(
          model: UserModel(),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0)),
              CupertinoButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                child: const Tooltip(
                  message: 'Back',
                  child: Text('Salvar comentario'),
                  excludeFromSemantics: true,
                ),
                onPressed: () {

                }
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
      body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(builder: (context, child, model){
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child:
                Container(
                  child: CommentStyle(widget.index, model),
                ),

            );

      }));
  }
}
```

Pronto, agora teu Widget `CommentStyle` está recebendo os devidos parâmetros ao ser criado.

**Explicação**

Como você está criando o Widget `CommentStyle` sem passar os parâmetros necessários, ao ser criado ele atribuí NULO para as propriedades.
Então ao tentar dar o `Print(index)` ele irá retornar NULL.

Comment: `ScopedModel` determina algumas funções relacionadas ao banco de dados. Resumidamente é como se fosse uma sessão do usuário.

Comment: @MarceloL verifique minha resposta novamente, fiz alguns ajustes para deixar ela mais detalhada.

Comment: Funcionou aqui @Matheus Ribeiro. Obrigado pela ajuda